# Django only show first POST element in loop

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I have simple library page that user can register, add and edit\delete records from library.

Template.html

```
{% extends "book/base.html" %}
{% block content %}

    <div class="row justify-content-center mt-5">
    </div>

 {% if books %}
      
      {% for book in books %}
<div class="table-users">
   <div class="header"> {{ book.title }} </a>   </div>
   <table cellspacing="0">
      <tr><center>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Author</th>
         <th>Delete</th>
</center>
      </tr>
         <td> {{ book.name }} </td>
         <td> {{ book.author }} </td>
         <td> <form class="delete" method="POST" action="{% url 'deletebook' book.id %}">  {% csrf_token %}  <button class="delete" type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Delete</button></td>
```

views.py:

```
def deletebook (request, book_pk):
    book = get_object_or_404(Book, pk=book_pk, user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        book.delete()
        return redirect('currentbooks')
```

With this loop only first element of POST method is active and working. Actually I'd debuggging html after rendered and i've seen that theres a only first element has a POST method. I searched on google and on stackoverflow and found something about the change id to class. But my template doesnt have any id. I also tried to move {% csrf_token %} outside of the loop but it doesnt work  either. I think so, i missed something important here.  I really appreciate if someone could help me out. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The code you are doing is correct if you want a table of books and delete button with seperate form for each which redirects to the same url with different id whenever hits the button. I think in the last line you have not added form end tag after button like this </form>. If you have already added it please provide full template.

Comment: Does you need the link to be a POST? Otherwise you can create it as a link, for example: `<a href="{% url 'deletebook' book.id %}"> Delete </a>` and then double-check permissions to delete on the view.

Comment: @Olivia Lundy, Specify your question.  Your question about the `for loop` or `post` method? What error did you get? Share also your view code for `currentbooks`.